# What is the name of this "ellipse"?

Tags: conic-sections

When I was in school, I learned what a circle was. Later, I learned what an ellipsis was. I also discovered that a circle is a particular case of ellipse (both foci at the same location).

Now, I'm pretty sure mathematicians have already studied *"generalized ellipsis"*. I mean ellipses with more than two foci.

What's the **name** of these mathematical objects?

*Some links to studies of these objects will be much appreciated.*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse